# How to update value of column x with value of column y?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a large table with a column x that I want to replicate to another column y in the same table. What would be the SQL statement for this?

The 1 st column is called `name` and it contains first name and last name separated by a space. How to move those to new first name and last name columns?

Comment: And what are you doing with names like `Elio de Angelis` or something like that?? Which space do you use to "split" that into first and last name??

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes names have extra spaces, this script will handle those situations

```
create table #t(name nvarchar(100), firstname nvarchar(50), lastname nvarchar(50))

insert #t (name) values ('Thomas Clausen')
insert #t (name) values ('  Bill Gates')
insert #t (name) values ('Steven Jobs  ')
insert #t (name) values ('Donald of Duck')
insert #t (name) values ('microsoft')
insert #t (name) values ('')

update #t 
set firstname = nullif(left(ltrim(name), charindex(' ', ltrim(name) + ' ')-1), ''),
lastname = nullif(stuff(rtrim(name), 1,len(rtrim(name))
           - charindex(' ', reverse(rtrim(name))), ''), '')
```

Result:

```
FirstName   LastName
Thomas      Clausen
Bill        Gates
Steven      Jobs
Donald      Duck
microsoft   NULL
NULL        NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update  YourTable
set     y = x
```

Comment: thanks eveyone, I updated the question slightly : ) see above

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

```
UPDATE Table
   SET y = x
```

Edited:

From the modification on your question I understand that you have a column 'name' with something like `John Adams` and want to fill two columns that already exist, FirstName and LastName. If that is the case, try this

```
UPDATE table
   SET FirstName = PARSENAME(REPLACE(name, ' ', '.'), 2),
       LastName = PARSENAME(REPLACE(name, ' ', '.'), 1)
```

If there's no space separating the first name and last name, no error message will be encountered and a NULL value will be returned for the FirstName while the whole full name will be returned as the LastName.

Comment: sorry, mine was to replicate in another table...didn't pay attention to that on your question...edited

Comment: if the 1 st column called name contains firstname and lastname diveded by a space how  to move those to new firstname and lastname column?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select t1.Name,t1.Marks as Maths,t2.Marks as physics,t3.Marks as Chemistry from 
(select T.Name,T.Marks,T.Subjects
from Student as T
where T.Subjects like 'Maths') as t1
inner join 
(select D.Name,D.Marks,D.Subjects
from Student as D
where D.Subjects like 'Physics') as t2
on t1.Name like t2.Name
inner join
(select E.Name,E.Marks,E.Subjects
from Student as E
where E.Subjects like 'Chemistry') as t3
on t2.Name like t3.Name
```